# How to apply __add__ method to an infinite count of class instances?

Tags: python

For example I have a class and by using `__add__` method on it's instances I want to add their salaries.

```
class Employee():
    def __init__(self,salary):
        self.salary = salary

    def __add__(self,other):
        return self.salary + other.salary

emp_1 = Employee(4000)
emp_2 = Employee(5000)
emp_3 = Employee(8000)
```

It does not work with 3 or more arguments:
`print(emp_1 + emp_2 + emp_3)` outputs
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Employee'`.
How can more than 2 instances be added up?

Comment: You would need to have the `__add__` method return a new `Employee` with the new salary, and then use `__repr__` to print the value.  Unless salary is the ONLY attribute these objects will have, this is not really a good design.  Operator overloading is a very dangerous and easily misused technique.

Comment: Adding employees doesn't logically make much sense. How do you add people? That aside, you could do it by adding an `__radd__()` method so that "number + Employee" works.

Comment: You're returning an integer from `__add__`, meaning the first two additions produce an integer, and integers don't know how to add `Employee` instances. As @TimRoberts notes, it's problematic to add instances like that, so just do it explicitly: `print(emp_1.salary + emp_2.salary + emp_3.salary)`

Comment: @TimRoberts Could you please attach some code?

Comment: @kindall I know that I could do it like that, however I want to understand how it can be done using only the instances.

Comment: You mean "indefinite", right? Python can't really do infinite sums out of the box.

Comment: @kindall Or, for an arbitrary number of employees, `print(sum(e.salary for e in [emp_1, emp_2, emp_3]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do, if you insist on continuing with this awful, terrible, no-good idea, is write your `__add__` method so it knows how to add both integers and `Employee` instances to itself, and also define `__radd__` so that when the left item is an integer, your class still gets a chance to do the addition.

Since addition of numbers is commutative, `__radd__` can just be the same as `__add__`.

```
class Employee():

    def __init__(self, salary):
        self.salary = salary

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Employee):
            other = other.salary
        return self.salary + other

    __radd__ = __add__
```

If you want to support any other object that has a `salary` attribute, not just instances of your `Employee` class, you can write `__add__` like:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    # get other.salary if it exists, otherwise just use other
    return self.salary + getattr(other, "salary", other)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it can be done, but I want to re-re-emphasize that this is a bad idea.  It doesn't make sense to add employees.  What happens when you add age or gender in here?  What gender would the temporary Employee instance have?

```
class Employee():
    def __init__(self,salary):
        self.salary = salary

    def __add__(self,other):
        return Employee(self.salary + other.salary)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"${self.salary}"

emp_1 = Employee(4000)
emp_2 = Employee(5000)
emp_3 = Employee(8000)
print( emp_1 + emp_2 + emp_3 )
```

Output:

```
$17000
```

### FOLLOWUP

Here's another way, based on sj95126's comment.  Here, the addition returns an integer, and we add an add override that can add itself to a simple integer.  This doesn't use the `__repr__` method.

```
class Employee():
    def __init__(self,salary):
        self.salary = salary

    def __radd__(self,other):
        return self.salary + other

    def __add__(self,other):
        return self.salary + other.salary

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"${self.salary}"

emp_1 = Employee(4000)
emp_2 = Employee(5000)
emp_3 = Employee(8000)
print( emp_1 + emp_2 + emp_3 )
```

Output:

```
17000
```

Comment: How can this be done without returning a new Employee instance?